# In python Tkinter, I have a scale (0 to 100), how to define a command that could limit the cursor of this scale to no more than 50?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The full code is like below, how to define the command?

```
import tkinter as tk
scale1 = tk.Scale(top, from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command= TO_BE_DEFINEED)
scale1.set(20)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you set the `command` to your own function? In that function you can get the value and check if it's >50. If it is, set it to 50. Is there anything else that changes the scale?

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you, it works, I wrongly thought there's another parameter for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
scale1 = tk.Scale(top, from_=0, to=50, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=TO_BE_DEFINEED)
                                  ^
                      limit ------'
```

parameter "to" is the limit just set it to 50